# dataSnapShot.getKey() not returning the actual push key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

i am trying to get that push key underline red with the reference of child name underline blue but my code returning products as key on dataSnapshot.getKey  here is code : 
**Code**

```
    Query reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").orderByChild("name").equalTo("iphon");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String key=dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.e(TAG,key);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

> 04-30 18:27:11.660 22742-22742/com.example.zar.shopistant E/MainActivity: products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So to get the snapshot of the individual child node, you need to loop over the result:

```
Query reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").orderByChild("name").equalTo("iphon");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key=childSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.i(TAG,key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please answer this one also can i get the whole object by that Query reference?